# Opening a modal when scrollbar is visible causes page to shift

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the modal code from the Bootstrap demo:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

If there's no scrollbar on the page, then opening a modal works fine (although it does overlay an unnecessary scrollbar on the right):

http://jsfiddle.net/ujGh4/1/

However, if there is a scrollbar visible, then opening a modal causes a very bad looking page shift:

http://jsfiddle.net/ujGh4/2/

I don't know if this happens in all browsers, but I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7 and here's a video of what happens:

http://www.screencast.com/t/vLlwtWiAsdQ0

How can this very ugly page shift be fixed?

Comment: This is a bug that should be fixed in the next release or the one after, for now read: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855#issuecomment-27198452

Comment: @cab well that's disappointing.. That issue was opened almost six months ago and it's still not fixed :-(

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855#issuecomment-27460362 - this has a fix

Comment: @cab I tried that and it doesn't work, unfortunately..

Comment: That sucks. Well, I just happened to be subscribed to the repo and noticed it, but I don't use the modal, I prefer fancyBox for this. Hope someone else comes along for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into the same problem, although I can't be 100% sure it's exactly the same.  Anyways, I fixed it by monkey-patching their javascript and adding a few CSS rules.  This was the best option for me so I wouldn't have to change their source code directly.

Here are the CSS rules:

```
// Make bootstrap's normal 'modal-open' class have no effect, 
// since we're going to use our own 'custom-modal-open' class

.modal-open {
  overflow: auto;
}

// Define our own custom class that we'll apply to the body element
// at the appropriate time (to prevent the shifting).

.custom-modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

// Also override the overflow value for the modal 'class'.  
// Bootstrap has it set to "scroll" which causes it to appear when
// it's not needed, and also makes the shift tougher to fix.

.modal {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's the coffeescript monkey-patch:

```
# Store bootstrap's 'modal' function for safe keeping,
# so we can use it within our custom version.

$.fn.old_modal = $.fn.modal
$.fn.modal = (option, related_target) ->

  # Call bootstrap's implementation.  It runs normally other
  # than the fact that the .modal-open rule has no effect.

  $(this).old_modal(option, related_target)
  modal_obj = $(this).data('bs.modal')

  # The 'modal' function can be called for other reasons, and 
  # we're only interested in the case of the modal being shown.

  if (modal_obj.options.show)
    $('body').addClass('custom-modal-open')
    $(this).on('hide.bs.modal', (e) =>

      # Super-hacky...copy the padding-right to the margin-right
      # so that we're responsible for removing it later.

      scroll_padding = $('body').css('padding-right')
      $('body').css('margin-right', scroll_padding)
      $(this).off('hide.bs.modal')
    )
$(this).on('hidden.bs.modal', (e) =>

  # The grand finale...remove the modal-open and right side padding
  # *gasp* at the SAME TIME.  Bad twitter. But thanks for having 
  # both the hide and hidden events to make this possible :)

  $('body').removeClass('custom-modal-open')
  $('body').css('margin-right', '')
  $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal')
)
```

Good luck...hopefully this fix works for you too.  It seems to work perfectly on Chrome and Firefox for me.